# Spring MVC parse web url Object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a GET request in the format below

```
http://www.example.com/companies?filters=%7B%22q%22%3A%22aaa%22%7D
```

After decode it is

```
filters={"q":"aaa"}
```

I have created an Object named `Filters` as below

```
public class Filters {
    private String q;
   //getter setter....
}
```

and in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<CompanyDTO> getCompanies(Filters filters) {
    filters.getQ();
    //do things
}
```

However, the `filters.getQ()` is `null`.

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the request parameter to the method argument.  Add @RequestParam to your method i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<CompanyDTO> getCompanies(@RequestParam(value="filters") Filters filters) {
    filters.getQ();
    //do things
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this before, it is not working. FYI here is the exception   "exception": "org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException",
  "message": "org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.Filters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.Filters]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found",

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @RequestParam, use @RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Instead of String filters=%7B%22q%22%3A%22aaa%22%7D, pass JSON object as parameter `http://www.example.com/companies?filters={"q":"aaa"}`

Comment: there is no exception, however, filters.getQ() is null.

Comment: please read http://java2practice.com/2013/03/14/how-to-pass-json-object-string-or-jsonarray-string-from-javascript-to-spring-controller/